# Deleting elements from different layers

Tags: qgis

I am using the QAD plugin.
The QAD-Dimensioning is working.
But when I want to erase the measurement it should be that way that I have not to select layer text first and erase the text then line-layer erasing line...

Is there a way to erase elements from different layers at the same time?

My layer-tree looks like this

```
layer-Measurement
    -layer-dim_line
    -layer-dim_symbol
    -layer-dim_text
```

Comment: Inherently that is not possible. If there was an easily determined value for those entries you do not need, you could build a graphical model that utilises the field calculator to choose all those entries/features which you want to keep and export them into new layers/shapefiles. Also, welcome to GIS SE.

Comment: thank you for you quick answer.
I will try to look for a way to someway "link" the shapefiles I want to delete elements/items from. And add a command which will do the work then...

Comment: Maybe you could fix your image and then we can point you better in the right direction. Most crucial is the question, which values you base your decision on to delete features.

Answer (score 1):

All QAD commands work on multiple layers at the same time.

If you want to erase elements from different layers at the same time, first of all you have to set them editable using `SETCURRUPDATEABLELAYERBYGRAPH` QAD command. Which allows you to set the layer status selecting graphical objects belonging to the interested layers.

Then you can run `ERASE` QAD command which prompt to select the objects you want to erase.